# MVVM + WPF. ComboBox. При изменении ItemsSource не подхватывается значение SelectedValue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, combobox

Имеет два ComboBox. ItemsSource второго ComboBox (topics) зависит от выбранного значения первого ComboBox(cities).
При начальной загрузки View все отображается нормально:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при изменении значения первого ComboBox(cities), Items подхватываются, но нет первого выбранного значения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя выполняется один и тот же код, что при начальной загрузке, что при изменении значения в рантайме.

В чем может быть проблема?

Код:

```
using Catel.MVVM;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Shell.Models;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Shell.ViewModels
{
    class PosterViewModel : ViewModelBase{
        public PosterViewModel() {
            this.cities = new ObservableCollection<City>{
                new City(1, "City 1", new ObservableCollection<Topic>{
                    new Topic(20, "Тема 1"),
                    new Topic(21, "Тема 2")
                }),
                new City(2, "City 2", new ObservableCollection<Topic>{
                    new Topic(22, "Тема 3"),
                    new Topic(23, "Тема 4")
                }),
                new City(3, "City 3", new ObservableCollection<Topic>{
                    new Topic(24, "Тема 5"),
                    new Topic(25, "Тема 6")
                }),
                new City(4, "City 4", new ObservableCollection<Topic>{
                    new Topic(26, "Тема 7"),
                    new Topic(27, "Тема 8")
                })
            };
            this.topics = new ObservableCollection<Topic>(this.cities[0].Topics);
            this.CityId = this.cities[0].Id;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<City> cities { get; private set; }

        private int cityId;
        public int CityId {
            get { return this.cityId; }
            set {
                this.cityId = value;
                City tmpCityForFind = new City(this.cityId, "", null);

                foreach (City city in this.cities) {
                    if (city.Equals(tmpCityForFind)) {
                        this.topics.Clear();

                        foreach (Topic topic in city.Topics){
                            this.topics.Add(new Topic(topic.Id, topic.TopicName));
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }
                this.topicId = this.topics[0].Id;
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Topic> topics { get; set; }
        public int topicId { get; set; }


        public string selectedValuePath { get; } = "Id";
    }
}
```

И XAML:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="CitySelect" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Margin="223,10,0,0" Width="120" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding cities}" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding CityId, Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectedValuePath="{Binding selectedValuePath}"/>

    <ComboBox x:Name="ThemeSelect" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Margin="367,10,0,0" Width="120"
              ItemsSource="{Binding topics}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding topicId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectedValuePath="{Binding selectedValuePath}"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              DisplayMemberPath="TopicName"/>
```

Comment: А зачем так сложно? Почему в сеттере CityId не просто `this.cityId = value; this.topics = value.Topics;`?

Comment: @VladD, и правда, Вы только что избавили от поиска с помощью foreach.
НО! Если написать this.topics = value.Topics;, то мы не увидем измененный ItemSource во втором ComBobox. Если подменять всю коллекцию, то изменения не отображаются, но если ИЗМЕНЯТЬ коллекцию, то изменения видимы

Comment: Ну это потому, что вы не отправляете `NotifyPropertyChanged` при изменении свойства `topics`.

Comment: Пробовал использовать NotifyPropertyChanged - довести до рабочего состояния не получилось. Да и не про topics речь, а о про topicId.

Comment: Ну окей, по вашей проблеме: а что имено вы хотите? Ну вот у вас есть выбранный элемент `"Тема 1"`, в комбобоксе появляются `"Тема 5"` и `"Тема 6"` — какой элемент должен оказаться выбранным, и по какой логике?

Comment: Когда меняется второй ItemsSources, то должно быть выбрано какое-то начальное значение (то есть из кода должен выбираться какой-то элемент из списка). Так и происходит при инициализации View: создается коллекция и задается значение SelectedValue, а вот при изменении коллекции SelectedValue уже не подхватывается.

Comment: @VladD, Вы оказались не правы в своем первом комментарии. value в моем случае - это id выбранного item, так что this.topics = value.Topics не будет работать.

Comment: А, ну это да. Уберите тогда `SelectedValuePath`, и пусть у вас `SelectedValue` будет иметь тип `Topic`. Зачем усложнять себе жизнь?